# Buildroot OS does not boot using qemu

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qemu, buildroot

I have compiled a small linux with framebuffer support & Qt, and i am now trying to run a simple Qt example.
My development environment is a Ubuntu 12.04 Ubuntu x32 (in a VM).
Qt 4.8 Version.  SDL enabled.

I am running the os with the following command:

```
qemu-system-i386 -kernel $KERNEL_FILE -hda $ROOT_FS_FILE -boot c -m 128M  -append "root=/dev/sda rw console=ttyS0,38400n8"
```

If I use --nographic it boots OK,  but without this option it shows the following message and then stops:

[image]

Comment: I guess you haven't added an init script to start the Qt app automatically? And you have forgotten to set BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT to tty1 instead of ttyS0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please build the `qemu_x86_defconfig` configuration:

```
make qemu_x86_defconfig
make
```

and then follow the instructions in `board/qemu/x86/readme.txt` to run it.

Comment: I have another problem while running the framebuffer example

Comment: I have enabled frame buffor support in 'make linux-menuconfig'